# lmer and mixed-effects modeling

Tags: mixed-model

I am trying to model, for marine plants (known as seagrasses), the effect of four factors: between-subjects factors Season and Depth, and within-subjects factors Class and Section (subjects are seagrass Shoots, pooled during sample treatment prior analysis; see fig. below), on the response variable 'concentration of the organosulfur compound DMSP'.

The structure of the dataframe is:

```
> 'data.frame': 230 obs. of 5 variables:
 $ DMSP     : num  102 93 96.5 74.7 66.3 ...
 $ Season   : Factor w/ 5 levels "2017-08","2017-11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Depth    : Factor w/ 5 levels "10","15","20",..: 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 ...
 $ Class    : Factor w/ 3 levels "int","inter",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Section  : Factor w/ 4 levels "0-10","10-20",..: 1 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 ...
>
```

The experimental design is described in the below picture:

[image]

This is, if I am right, a nested structure with fixed and random effects, isn't it? I have started writing a lmer model (lme4 package) in R. I can write the model for the two between-subjects factors Season and Depth (fully crossed), but I am not sure how to properly code for the within-subjects factors Class and Section (... to be completed).

```
lmer. <- lmer(DMSP ~ 1 + Season * Depth ... , data = DMSP.df)
```

Could anyone help with that case study and give some explanations on the model writing? Thanks.

Comment: You say you are interested in "*the effect of four factors: between-subjetcts factors Season and Depth*" which implies that they should be modelled as fixed effects, not random effects, since modelling them as random will only provide a variance. Can you clarify what your research question is ?

Comment: Dear Robert Long, thanks for helping. My Research question is: I want to test the effecy of between-subjects factors Season and Depth and within-subjects factors leaf Class and leaf Section on DMSP concentration. I published a related post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443511/mixed-model-with-split-plot-design

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "effecy" ? Ah yes I remember you other post. To clarify, are you trying to find out how Season, Depth, Class and Section are mutually associated with DMSP ? Do you want to find some kind of equation which relates these 4 variables to the outcome ?

Comment: Typing error, sorry, I mean 'effect'. So yes, I want to find an equation (using lmer?) which relates these 4 variables (and interactions) to the outcome. Do I give proper information with the sampling design picture, the above research question and the dataframe structure? I have been completely blocked for days with that question.

Comment: Are the leaves divided into sections because you expect a systematic  difference between the measurements at each section, or just to provide additional measures (replications) ? Also, is each section measured only once ?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Leaves are divided into sections because we expect difference between sections (and between classes as well), with DMSP concentration decreasing from the basal 0-10cm section to the top 30-40cm section (vertical growth of the leaf, so DMSP concentration decreases with leaf section 'aging'). Each section is measured 3 times on one single leaf class (three analytical pseudoreplicates for analytical CV determination); but as shown in the sampling design figure, we sampled 3 seagrasses, so n = 3 for each section (9 if accounting for analytical pseudoreplicates).

Comment: Is there any temporal trend anticipated ? For instance do you expect DMSP to change as a function of time, perhaps due to growth of the shoots, or have you repeated the sampling simply to acquire more data ?

Comment: We expect differences among leaf classes and leaf sections (with tissue aging). We also expect changes as a function of time/Season (we know concentrations evolve in time, ie, when the plant is getting older; https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2019.00510/full). We still do not know the effect of depth. The repeated sampling therefore was NOT to acquire more data, but to study changes as a function of time. In fact, factors Season, Class and Section are all related to the plant aging; depth is independant to the plant aging.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions ! I'm a little confused about classes.  You take a sample of 3 shoots, and these  contain 3 classes (external, middle and internal) which are then separated, and once separated, you then divide each class into 5 sections. I think I may have misunderstood because that doesn't quite make sense to me - are there always exactly 3 classes in each shoot ?  Or perhaps the class is a property of the individual shoot ? That distinction seems quite important for modelling.